# C++ Expression Tree Simplification

Tags: c++, string, tree, expression, deque

I'm having trouble simplifying an expression tree string. I've tried using stacks to separate parenthesis from elements then popping any unnecessary parentheses, but at this point I've just created a mess and am trying to start back from scratch, so if I'm given the expression:

```
Input: (AB)C((DE)F)
```

(I assume this is what the tree looks like):
[image: Desired tree]
With that string and that tree my output should be:

```
Output: ABC(DEF)
```

I just don't understand how to get from the input to the output.

Comment: How much do you know about trees and the ways to [traverse them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal)? A couple of quick searched about *tree traversal* or *tree walking* should give you enough to read that you hopefully will be able to figure it out yourself.

Comment: i know how to traverse them and how to manipulate them i just have no idea how to do it when all i have to work with is a single string, and a basic data structures.

Comment: Then do it in a two-step process? Take the input string and actually *create* the tree, then traverse the tree to create the output string.

Comment: ok but how can i detect a which parentheses are redundent? the input can be changed.  ie instead i might be given: 

    Input: (AB)C
    Output: ABC

Comment: Maybe you should read about [*parsing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) and [*abstract syntax trees*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) instead?

Comment: What are the rules for simplification? (An example or two does not make a rule.)

Comment: @molbdnilo the simplify operation will remove the parentheses around the very first element in the expression tree and in each of its sub-expression trees. Also simplifying multiple times should have the same result as simplifying once.